# User permission to a particular command

Tags: command-line, permissions

As a new member, I just want to say I've had great advice from this forum so far and you guys have been so helpful - so, thank you for that!

I have just set up Ubuntu server for the first time and, so far, it's doing everything I want it to do. It's only temporary and for a few students who need to perform a few simple tasks.
Once of the tasks include demonstrating how to use traceroute. I've installed traceroute and, due to some firewall issue, the only way I can get it to work properly is to use the -I parameter. However, a normal user can't use the -I parameter and I don't particularly want to give the users full superuser permissions to do so. Is there a way I can give the users this particular permission but nothing else?

Once I've done that, I'll be ready to go. Everything has gone well so far!

Comment: This is great. I've followed the instructions for on the duplicate question. I'm just unsure where the traceroute command is located so I can edit the file in sudoers.d